# How to update frame for more objects class Enemy in Array<Enemy>?

Tags: java, libgdx

I have an List that contains type Enemy, I populate this list using the below loop:

```
for(....) {
arrayEnemy.add(new Enemy(new Rectangle(50.50f, 50.50f, 
Enemy.WIDTH, Enemy.HEIGHT), 
facesRight? 0.10f : -0.10f, 0.7f));
}
```

and cheking objects Enemy:

```
    if(arrayEnemy.get(num).isDie){
        arrayEnemy.get(num).rendCountAnim++;                
        arrayEnemy.get(num).setStateEnemy(Enemy.StateEnemy.Deadening);
        arrayEnemy.get(num).getStateEnemy();                
        if (TimeUtils.millis()>(arrayEnemy.get(num).startTimeAnim+35100)) {
            arrayEnemy.removeIndex(num);
            break;
        }
    }
```

The Enemy class:

```
 public class Enemy {
    enum StateEnemy {
         Walking, Deadening
    }

    public StateEnemy stateEnemy = StateEnemy.Walking;
    static float WIDTH;
    static float HEIGHT;
    public boolean isDie = false;
    private Rectangle rect;
    private float velocityX;
    private float velocityY;
    public long startTimeAnim = TimeUtils.millis();
    public int rendCountAnim = 0;

    public Enemy(Rectangle rect, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        this.rect = rect;
        this.WIDTH=rect.width;
        this.HEIGHT=rect.height;        
        this.velocityX = velocityX;
        this.velocityY = velocityY; 
    }

    public StateEnemy getStateEnemy() {
        return stateEnemy;
    }

    public void setStateEnemy(StateEnemy stateEnemy) {
        this.stateEnemy = stateEnemy;
    }

    public void moveX() {
        rect.x += velocityX;
    }
    public void moveY() {
        rect.y += velocityY;
    }

    public float getOldPointCellX(){    
        return oldPointCellX;
    }
    public float getOldPointCellY(){    
        return oldPointCellY;
    }

    public Rectangle getRect() {
        return rect;
    }

    public float getVelocityX() {
        return velocityX;
    }
    public void setVelocityX(float velocity) {
        this.velocityX = velocity;
    }
    public float getVelocityY() {
        return velocityY;
    }
    public void setVelocityY(float velocity) {
        this.velocityY = velocity;
    }
}
```

They are all walking on the ground, as expected. BUT!!! I kill one of the enemies, but ALL of the enemies animations change! This is the render method code:

```
TextureRegion frameEnemy = null;
        if(arrayEnemy.size != 0){
            switch (arrayEnemy.get(num).getStateEnemy()) {

            case Walking:
                frameEnemy = animWalkEnemy.getKeyFrame(stateTime);
                break;  
            case Deadening:
                frameEnemy = animDeadEnemy.getKeyFrame(stateTime);
                break;  
            }
        }

        for(num=0; num < arrayEnemy.size; num++){
            batch.draw(frameEnemy, arrayEnemy.get(num).getRect().x,
            arrayEnemy.get(num).getRect().y, 
            Enemy.WIDTH, Enemy.HEIGHT);
        }
```

How can I make the animation occur on a single instance of the Enemy instead of all of them?

Comment: We don't have all your code (and please don't post it), but shouldn't your `switch` statement be inside the loop, or something? It looks like you set `frameEnemy` of `num`, but what is the value of `num` in the `switch` statement? Then you iterate over `arrayEnemy` from 0 to `size`, but you're using the same `frameEnemy` for all of them.

Comment: @DavidS I do then? I do not understand what's going on!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like [DavidS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/201891/davids) pointed out in the comments, you should set the `frameEnemy` for each `Enemy` object separately. You can do this as follows

```
for(Enemy enemy : arrayEnemy) {
    //Set the animation texture for the enemy object
    switch (enemy.getStateEnemy()) {
        case Walking:
            frameEnemy = animWalkEnemy.getKeyFrame(stateTime);
            break;  
        case Deadening:
            frameEnemy = animDeadEnemy.getKeyFrame(stateTime);
            break;  
    }

    //Render the enemy object
    batch.draw(frameEnemy, enemy.getRect().x, enemy.getRect().y, Enemy.WIDTH, Enemy.HEIGHT);
}
```

Comment: It remained unchanged

Comment: thank youuuuu !!! it's worked now !!! i changed your code this switch (enemy.getStateEnemy())  thank yoooouuuu!!!!

Comment: Oh thanks for pointing that out. I'll edit my answer in case anyone else runs into the same problem :)

Comment: now my animation disappears quickly. though it is written in the code TimeUtils.millis()>(arrayEnemy.get(num).startTimeAnim+35100)

Comment: Can you share your `render` method here?

Comment: omg i have java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: index can't be >= size: 1 >= 1

Comment: Create a gist on github and share the link here

Comment: i found exceptions and fix it! :) ok i share you link to bitbucket

Comment: If everything is working properly then there is no need to share your code. But if you still have some problems then feel free to share and ask.

Comment: there link bitbucket [link]( https://bitbucket.org/ir00t/game-dev-maven)

Comment: warn the download is completed. because it was a private repository

Comment: *Sigh* this won't work. Bitbucket maintains private repos. So the only way for me to view your code is if you grant me access to it.

Comment: i open this repos.

Comment: Sorry but I still can't view it. It says that I don't have access to this repository.

Comment: and now ? open?

Comment: Do not be afraid of my code :) I'm a novice(beginner) programmer)))

Comment: Hahaha no problem. I'm a beginner too.

Comment: if you run the game. Right at the beginning of gray pipe, stand on it and press down :)